# What temperature metric does the Tiva C LMF120XL measure?

Tags: sensor, c, arm, cortex-m0

I'm writing a program based on the udemy course I'm following. The program I'm writing will blink a different color based on what temperature the sensor is reading in from ADCO using SS3. At one point, the instructor of the course does this conversion, to, I'm assuming, celsius:

```
temperature = 147 - (247 * ADC0->SSFIFO3) / pow(2,12)
```

Can someone explain this conversion? I am assuming the 2^12 has something to do with the ADC being 12-bit.

Comment: This would be why we never use "magic numbers" in professional programming. Each of those need to be replaced with a somewhat self-explanatory identifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example is using the internal temperature sensor of the MCU. You can find the nominal conversion equations for the sensor in the MCU datasheet.

[image]

You can see that the numbers have been rounded to integers, assuming a (VREFP - VREFN) of 3.3V nominal (supply voltage used as ADC reference).

As typical for this sort of thing, the internal sensor is rather crude and has poorly guaranteed characteristics:

[image]

You should be able to derive the equation from the ADC characteristics and typical sensor characteristics.

To get the most out of a course such as this, you should be continuously referring to the MCU datasheet and the eval board schematic (and datasheets of any other relevant components).

Comment: Ah, thanks! I do my best to scan the data sheet all I can but didn't see this when ctrl +f'ing "temperature sensor" for some reason